# Can we add multiple schema.org JSON-LD code blocks to the home page of a website?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

Can we add multiple JSON Code on a website like organization, services, local business?

Comment: For what purpose? Can you include an example?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. In fact, it can frequently be useful to break up your JSON-LD structured data code snippets into smaller blocks of reusable scripts. This can prevent you from having to build and deploy a custom block for every single page, and from ending up with code that describes attributes that don't appear on a page. (You'll want to [follow the guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies) and [test your code](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).) Think of it as Atomic Design blocks for structured data.

Let's say your home page has a logo that appears on every page, corporate contact info, and a video. You also have a Contact page. Sure, you can combine the logo and contact info into one code block, but you can add the video markup via a second code block. That way, when you deploy your structured data on the Contact page, you can use the first block but leave out the video block.

Google doesn't care how many separate scripts you have, only that they're the right scripts for the page.